# Reading JSON Hierarchies to Target Fields and Loop Through Each Result

Tags: php, json, loops, hierarchy

I am using the Zoho CRM API to view contacts. I am returning the response in JSON format. Here is my code:

```
$token="03430403423mysecrettokenhere03403";
$url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords?";
$url .= "authtoken=".$token."&scope=crmapi";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
echo "</pre>";

foreach ($obj as $testme) {
    $test = $obj->results[0]->Company;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "test: " . $test;
}
```

Raw response:

```
stdClass Object
(
[response] => stdClass Object
    (
        [result] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Leads] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [row] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [no] => 1
                                        [FL] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000103005
                                                        [val] => LEADID
                                                    )

                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                                                        [val] => SMOWNERID
                                                    )

                                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => chase
                                                        [val] => Lead Owner
                                                    )

                                                [3] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => Testttt
                                                        [val] => Company
                                                    )

                                                [4] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => Test
                                                        [val] => First Name
                                                    )

                                                [5] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => Lead
                                                        [val] => Last Name
                                                    )

                                                [6] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => testlead@test.com
                                                        [val] => Email
                                                    )

                                                [7] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 0
                                                        [val] => No of Employees
                                                    )

                                                [8] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 0
                                                        [val] => Annual Revenue
                                                    )

                                                [9] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                                                        [val] => SMCREATORID
                                                    )

                                                [10] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => chase
                                                        [val] => Created By
                                                    )

                                                [11] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                                                        [val] => MODIFIEDBY
                                                    )

                                                [12] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => chase
                                                        [val] => Modified By
                                                    )

                                                [13] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 2016-05-16 16:04:37
                                                        [val] => Created Time
                                                    )

                                                [14] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 2016-05-16 16:04:37
                                                        [val] => Modified Time
                                                    )

                                                [15] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => false
                                                        [val] => Email Opt Out
                                                    )

                                                [16] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 2016-05-16 16:04:37
                                                        [val] => Last Activity Time
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [no] => 2
                                        [FL] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000100023
                                                        [val] => LEADID
                                                    )

                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                                                        [val] => SMOWNERID
                                                    )

                                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => chase
                                                        [val] => Lead Owner
                                                    )

                                                [3] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => Test
                                                        [val] => First Name
                                                    )

                                                [4] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => Lead
                                                        [val] => Last Name
                                                    )

                                                [5] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => testlead@test.com
                                                        [val] => Email
                                                    )

                                                [6] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 0
                                                        [val] => No of Employees
                                                    )

                                                [7] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 0
                                                        [val] => Annual Revenue
                                                    )

                                                [8] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                                                        [val] => SMCREATORID
                                                    )

                                                [9] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => chase
                                                        [val] => Created By
                                                    )

                                                [10] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                                                        [val] => MODIFIEDBY
                                                    )

                                                [11] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => chase
                                                        [val] => Modified By
                                                    )

                                                [12] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 2016-05-16 13:15:29
                                                        [val] => Created Time
                                                    )

                                                [13] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 2016-05-16 13:15:29
                                                        [val] => Modified Time
                                                    )

                                                [14] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => false
                                                        [val] => Email Opt Out
                                                    )

                                                [15] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [content] => 2016-05-16 13:15:29
                                                        [val] => Last Activity Time
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [uri] => /crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords
    )

)

test:
```

Question 1:

How do I read the hierarchy and target the fields like "Company" and "First Name" "Last Name" etc. I'd like to be able to output these fields for each contact.

```
$test = $obj->response->results->Accounts->row;
```

This is as far as I can get.

Question 2:

I currently have two contacts in there for testing. How can I loop through each one?

```
foreach ($obj as $testme) {
    $test = $obj->results[0]->Company;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "test: " . $test;
}
```

The current loop above is only returning one object.

Comment: Post (part of) the JSON response in your question. Many SO users don't like to click unknown off-site links.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still learning the SO ways! I edited the post to display the raw response

Comment: Where is company in this JSON response?

Comment: Not sure how it got omitted... but I updated the response to show it. its [3]. And its only shown for the first contact object

Comment: Cleary $obj->results[0]->Company is not the correct path but I don't understand how to read the hierarchy @EatPeanutButter

Answer (score 1):

OK, assuming these JSON return arrays always come back the same way, your could do something like this.  First, clean up that return object by stripping away all the wrapper junk:

```
$cleanObj = $return->response->results->Leads->row;
```

Then use a simple function to loop through the array for each contact:

```
function getCompany($obj, $part) {
    $innerObj = $obj->FL;
    foreach ($innerObj as $c)  {
        if ($c['val'] == $part) {
            return $c['content'];
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pass in one of the contacts and the part you want.

```
$company = getCompany($cleanObj[0], "Company");
```

Untested (mainly because I don't feel like reproducing the data dump), but this should grab "Testttt" from your first contact.

As for your second question, you can simply loop through the `$cleanObj` array to access all of your contacts.  Instead of `$cleanObj[0]`, do `$cleanObj[1]` and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am getting the "invalid argument supplied foreach" error though..

Comment: `var_dump()` the $innerObj and the $obj to make sure the path is correct. There's a lot of layers around the data you want.  They may need to be tweaked.

Comment: NULL and NULL for both variables

Comment: May want to change $cleanObj to `$return->response->results->Leads->row;` (fixed capitalization)

Comment: And of course change `$return` to whatever you called the decoded JSON

Comment: Appreciate the continued help. I updated the line with the Leads capitalized. Still returning NULL though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112095/discussion-between-eatpeanutbutter-and-cpcdev).